# how to organize your projects and dags with airflow

Tags: airflow

I am considering using Apache-Airflow. I had a look at the documentation and now I am trying to implement an already existing pipeline (home made framework) using Airflow.

All given examples are simple one module DAGs. But in real life you can have a versionned application that provides (complex) pipeline blocks. And DAGs use those blocks as tasks. Basically the application package is installed in a dedicated virtual environment with its dependencies.

Ok so no now how do you plug that with Airflow ? Should airflow be installed in the application virtualenv ? Then there is a dedicated Airflow instance for this application pipelines. But in this case if you have 100 applications you have to have 100 Airflow instances... On the other side if you have one unique instance it means you have installed all your applications packages on the same environement and potentially you can have dependency conflicts...

Is there something I am missing ? Are there best practices ? Do you know internet resources that may help ? Or GitHub repos using one pattern or the other ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

One instance with 100 pipelines. Each pipelines can easily be versioned and python dependancies can be packaged.

We have 200+ very different pipelines and use one central airflow instance. Folders are organized as follow:

```
DAGs/
DAGs/pipeline_1/v1/pipeline_1_dag_1.0.py
DAGs/pipeline_1/v1/dependancies/
DAGs/pipeline_1/v2/pipeline_1_dag_2.0.py
DAGs/pipeline_1/v2/dependancies/
DAGs/pipeline_2/v5/pipeline_2_dag_5.0.py
DAGs/pipeline_2/v5/dependancies/
DAGs/pipeline_2/v6/pipeline_2_dag_6.0.py
DAGs/pipeline_2/v6/dependancies/
etc.
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. What does the dependancies folders contain ? Python modules/packages ? Suppose one python module of pipeline 1 depends on awesome-package v1 and another module of pipeline 2 depends on awesome-package v2. And that awesome-package v1 and awesome-package v2 are not compatible. How do you manage that ?

Comment: I'd appreciate more detail on the contents of the DAG file. For instance, you cannot copy a DAG to another name without changing the contents; most notable is the DAG ID, so you must be dynamically or manually defining the DAG ID for each pipeline and version.